# Python boto3: receive versionId after uploading a file to S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to upload a file to a version-enabled S3 bucket and need its version number. Ideally, without a separate API call to avoid any possibility of a race condition. I'm using the following code snippet for upload (which is working fine):

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
s3.upload_fileobj(file_handle, bucket_name, key)
```

The response of this function is `None` and I can't really see how it is defined in boto3, so it's hard to dive any deeper into it.

The official S3 documentation mentions that the version id is included in the header of the response after upload. However, I can't see how I can access this header with `boto3`.

Is this possible at all? If yes: how? If no: How can I hack boto3 so I can access this response header?

Fyi, I'm using `boto3==1.9.64`

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**
[Here the link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AddingObjectstoVersioningEnabledBuckets.html) to S3 documentation that talks about the `x-amz-version-id` header

Comment: Can you link the docs that say you get a response? The docs for `upload_fileobj` don't mention a response. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj

Comment: Yes sorry. I edited my question

Comment: It looks like that header is returned when you use the REST API rather than `upload_fileobj` in boto3. You could try heading the object as soon as you initiate the upload. I don't think this will cause a race condition because `upload_fileobj` would have thrown an error if the upload didn't start. I'm not 100% sure on that though so using `put_object` as suggested by @jarmod is probably the easiest way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [put_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) with file-like objects. It returns `VersionId` in the response dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

I was doing s3 to s3 copy, and hence did not want to use `put_object`. For anyone else who is fine with making an extra call to get the versionId, can use the code below:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
version_id:str = s3_client.head_object(
    Bucket='bucket-name', Key='key'
)['VersionId']
```